# How to convert a comma delimited String into LinkedHashSet in Scala

Tags: scala

Is there an easy way to convert a comma delimited String into a LinkedHashSet in Scala?  The goal is to remove duplicates in the string, but it needs a FOR loop. So I thought I could just split the String into a collection like LinkedHashSet that can preserve the original order and also remove duplicates.  I did some research, but didn't find a way.  So just want to confirm here if it's feasible.

For example, for String:

```
 aaa, bbb, ccc, aaa, ddd
```

I want to make the to be:

```
   aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really need `LinkedHashSet`. Scala collections have convenient method `distinct`:

```
"aaa, bbb, ccc, aaa, ddd".split(", ").distinct.mkString(", ")
```

Produces:

```
res0: String = aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd
```

Comment: This is the scala way! Just to clarify: Take a `String`, turn it into some list of string and turn this into a `distinct` list. That's it.

Comment: @isaias-b, strictly speaking, there is no conversion to `List`. `split` returns `Array[String]` which is implicitly wrapped in `ArrayOps[String]` which extends `SeqLike[String]`, where `distinct` is defined.

Comment: I was too lazy to lookup the exact types, but you are absolutely right! ;)

Comment: Thank you very much.  This eliminates the use of the collection

Comment: @jlp, well, technically, it doesn't *eliminate* usage of `Set`, it just hides implementation details from you. Using `HashSet` is the most efficient way to eliminate duplicates anyway.

Answer (score 3):

It is as simple as this:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet
scala> "aaa, bbb, aaa, ccc, ddd".split(", ").to[LinkedHashSet]
res12: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet[String] = Set(aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd)
```

you could use `ListSet` that is immutable as well, although set will be in reverse order

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable.ListSet
scala> "aaa, bbb, aaa, ccc, ddd".split(", ").to[ListSet]
res0: scala.collection.immutable.ListSet[String] = ListSet(ddd, ccc, bbb, aaa)
scala> res0.toList.reverse
res1: List[String] = List(aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd)
```